# Change actionbar button background color when pressed

Tags: android, button, colors, background, android-actionbar

If I press a button in the action bar, then its background color is not what I want. The background color of my item doesn't respond to my click event. How can I change this and change the background color when it's pressed?

Comment: You got to customize you actionbar. Check out this two links [Customizing ActionBar](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) [Custom ActionBar](https://code.google.com/p/styled-action-bar/)

Comment: i think you need this link too: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to declare [`android:actionBarItemBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarItemBackground) attribute which is a:

> Custom item state list drawable background for action bar items.

Then, in your styles do as follows:

```
<style name="CustomStyle" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
</style>
```

So, put your own drawable with a `selector` and every state (pressed, focused, disabled, etc) to have the expected background. For example, the drawable `ab_item_background.xml` declared above might be like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <!-- focused/pressed: color=red -->
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <!-- pressed: color=red -->
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <!-- normal: color=transparent -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

In [Styling the Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style), you can find all the customization possibles and all the attributes to do so.

Comment: Fixed it by using DarkActionBar

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks.. Just one thing though ``android:actionBarItemBackground`` is being understood by Android while ``actionBarItemBackground`` is giving error so I removed it, is it necessary to have both?

Comment: It depends of your actionbar @RohanKandwal. If you use SherlockAB or the Support library, you have to use it, yes.

Comment: @Fllo I use Support library, as I said, ``actionBarItemBackground `` gave error while compiling so I removed it. In this case, how can I use both.

Comment: I see @RohanKandwal. When you write these attributes in style.xml, you have to close this file, clean and save your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0a0a0a")));
```

this might help

Comment: This is change background color for actionbar, not for home button