# Change button background color on click in AppCompat Actionbar

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, background-color

I have a blue `ActionBar`, and when I click on the hamburger icon (to open the menu), the default `click` background color (selector) gets lost in the `ActionBar` background color.

This is why I wanted to change the backgroud click color for the items in the ActionBar.

Notice that I am using `AppCompat`.

I have my styles.xml like this, trying with `actionBarItemBackground` without success:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle"   tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background"  tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/azul</item>
        <item name="background">@color/azul</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/click_background</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/click_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blanco</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

My click selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- NOTE: order is important (the first matching state(s) is what is rendered) -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

How can I change the Buttons background color `on click` in the `ActionBar`?

This is not duplication from [Change actionbar button background color when pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640136/change-actionbar-button-background-color-when-pressed). My problem is not solved there.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640136/change-actionbar-button-background-color-when-pressed

Comment: you must be kidding. Did you see my question? I said I already used actionBarItemBackground, and is there in my code. Whats the diference between that link and my code? Please, the code I defined is not changing the background color. I might think is because I am using AppCompat

Comment: @Frank N. Stein please remove the "duplicate". This is not duplicate from that question because is not working. My question is more specific: for AppCompat. The code in that answer does not work for my case. Before I asked this question, I tried that answer without success, thats why I asked...

Comment: If you weren't able to make it work. it doesn't mean that it doesn't work. You simply have to adapt it to your specific case.

Comment: That does not help me at all. I am asking here because I was not able to make it work. The answer in that link does not help me and I can't realize how to make it work in my case. That's why I created this post. And I think that's why Stackoverflow was created for. If you are closing posts just to earn points and reputation, you are not helping the comunity. There might be people with the same problem, and you are just a pain in the neck.