# Change menu action bar icons background color to a opacity circle programmatically (not the whole toolbar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

I want to change the background color of the action bar / menu icons to an opacity circle (NOT the color of the whole action bar).

I have a transparent action bar and sometimes the icons get faded in with the background picture (the white arrow on the left and the 3 dots on the right):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 Drawable navIcon = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
 assert navIcon != null;

 Drawable actionMenuIcon = menu.findItem(R.id.action_view_action_menu).getIcon();
 assert actionMenuIcon != null;
```

When a user scrolls a top bar appears and changes the color of the icon itself. But I want to programmatically put a background circle behind the icons so they don't fade in with the transparent background. Here is the code for changing the color of the icon on scroll:

```
    ValueAnimator iconAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(fromColor, toColor);
    iconAnimation.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime));
    iconAnimation.addUpdateListener(animator -> {
        navIcon.setColorFilter((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        actionMenuIcon.setColorFilter((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    });
    iconAnimation.start();
```

Can anyone help programmatically put a background circle behind the icons so they don't fade into the picture?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640136/change-actionbar-button-background-color-when-pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640136/change-actionbar-button-background-color-when-pressed): you need to set another background drawable to your action button, so you swap one state list drawable for another on scroll

Answer (score 0):

try to use drawable xml  with layers/state list. and/or create/modify ripple effect